# Chart not displaying in ionic5

Tags: chart.js, ionic5

**I copied this tutorial but the charts are not displaying. Btw I already registered the registrable. And I'm not getting any error. It's just not displaying the charts. Can you me help guys?** < [https://javascript.plainenglish.io/ionic-5-charts-graphs-using-chartjs-library-5ce69b83b2a9>](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/ionic-5-charts-graphs-using-chartjs-library-5ce69b83b2a9%3E)

Comment: You need to provide more information like your block of code, how it failed, what the errors are, etc.

Comment: Please don't **shout** at us!